# Remotely reinstall dbus and libdbus

Tags: shell, scripting, dbus

OS: Ubuntu 11.04 amd64

After several updates, dbus didn't get to install correctly (carelessly used &&; long night), which I found out after server restart – no network services are accessible.

Only way that I can connect is to request recovery system to be loaded (via serverloft backend). I can mount disks and put needed files.

So basically my approach would be to create a shell script that removes corrupted dbus (and libdbus?) and installs [from source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/1.4.6-1ubuntu6).

Any tips; could there occur any other issues that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount disks in the rescue environment, `chroot` into the system, and fix the broken packages.  Don't bother scripting it, you're only dealing with a once-off situation.